# MySQL Error #1025, Access Denied for 'user'@'host' (using password yes)

Tags: mysql, windows, mariadb

i added a user to my mariadb on my ubuntu server:

```
CREATE USER 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'passwd';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'user'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

CREATE USER 'user'@'localhost';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'user'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

i checked the mysql config files, port is 3306 (standard) and bind-address is set to the external network ip for allow connections from outside. i changed nothing else in the settings.

connection from the shell in ubuntu works without any problems, now i want to connect from my windows home computer via console and mysql command to the server.

> mysql -h servername -u user -p --port=3306

but i get an

> error 1045, access denid for 'user'@'host' (using password: YES)

if i add a user with the host i become from my ISP it works. but i thought % is standing for a all hosts and only rejects localhost connections. the problem is, i have a changing host because i'm using differen computers at different places and don't want to add 20 users.

Comment: @SloanThrasher, added, but the connection is exactly the same i think

Comment: @SloanThrasher - In 99% of Questions, the Answer will be the same for MySQL and MariaDB.  Off hand, this looks like such a Question.  It is probably best to tag with both for MariaDB questions -- more eyeballs to help.

Comment: @TypedSource - What version?  There have been changes in recent version to the authentication process.  And, is the server in some Cloud; they may have other issues.

Comment: @RickJames i installed a fresh ubuntu 16 today and have done all updates. the sql server is the newest stable fresh from the apt-sources. how i told, it works if i add the complete host to my user, what not works is the placeholder % for accepting any host.

Comment: @RickJames do you use 'u' in your text? or do you allway write 'you' ?  "I LOVE U" ? and by the way, its called MSSQL-Server not SQL Server, SQL is a language which is provided by more than one Software

Comment: i got it working with a username that is not linux user too. so i think it's something in combination with the linux user